# how to grep this Javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object structure:

```
var mapData = 
{
   Summary:
   {
      ReportName: 'Month End Report'
   },
   NortheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 123,
      RegionName: 'Northeast'
   },
   SoutheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 456,
      RegionName: 'Southeast'   
   },   
}
```

I want to write a grep function that returns an array of region names. The following function is not returning any values:

```
var regions = $.grep(mapData, function(n,i)
{
   return n.RegionName;
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure but should it be n.RegionName on the return statement?

Comment: There's no JSON here. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: also its not an array.

Comment: why don't you write your own function?

Comment: sure - javascript object in this example but the same grep logic should be usable on a json object with a few small tweaks

Comment: I think you want `$.map`, not `$.grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn `$.grep` to **$.map** and you would good to go.

```
var regions = $.map(mapData, function(n,i)
{
   return n.RegionName;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`$.grep` is for filtering arrays. Your structure isn't an array. `$.grep` is also *just* for filtering, but you're talking about both filtering (leaving out `Summary`) and mapping (getting just the region names).

Instead, you can use

- `Object.keys` and `push`:

  ```
  var regions = [];
  Object.keys(mapData).forEach(function(key) {
      var entry = mapData[key];
      if (entry && entry.RegionName) {
          regions.push(entry.RegionName);
      }
  });
  ```
- `Object.keys`, `filter`, and `map`:

  ```
  var regions = Object.keys(mapData)
      .filter(function(key) {
          return !!mapData[key].RegionName;
      })
      .map(function(key) {
          return mapData[key].RegionName;
      });
  ```
- A `for-in` loop and `push`:

  ```
  var regions = [];
  for (var key in mapData) {
       if (mapData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           var entry = mapData[key];
           if (entry && entry.RegionName) {
               regions.push(entry.RegionName);
           }
       }
  }
  ```

...probably others.

Comment: @oboshto: Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

That's an object, not an array. According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/), your above example would work if `mapData` were an array.

You can use [lodash's mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mapValues) for this type of thing:

```
var regions = _.mapValues(mapData, function(o) {
  return o.RegionName;
});
```

ES6:

```
const regions = _.mapValues(mapData, o => o.RegionName)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [`jQuery.grep()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/), you should pass an array as data to be searched, but `mapData` is an object. However, you can loop through the object keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), but AFAIK you'll have to use function specific for your case, like:

```js
var mapData = 
{
   Summary:
   {
      ReportName: 'Month End Report'
   },
   NortheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 123,
      RegionName: 'Northeast'
   },
   SoutheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 456,
      RegionName: 'Southeast'   
   },   
};

var keys = Object.keys(mapData),
    result = [];

console.log(keys);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  var region = mapData[key].RegionName;
  
  if (region && result.indexOf(region) == -1) {
    result.push(region);
  }
});

console.log(result);

// Short version - based on @KooiInc answer
console.log(
  Object.keys(mapData).map(m => mapData[m].RegionName).filter(m => m)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.grep` is used for arrays. `mapData` is an object. You could try using map/filter for the keys of `mapData`, something like:

```js
var mapData = 
{
   Summary:
   {
      ReportName: 'Month End Report'
   },
   NortheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 123,
      RegionName: 'Northeast'
   },
   SoutheastRegion:
   {
      Property1: 456,
      RegionName: 'Southeast'   
   },   
};

var regionNames = Object.keys(mapData)
 .map( function (key) { return mapData[key].RegionName; } )
 .filter( function (name) { return name; } );
console.dir(regionNames);

// es2105 
var regionNames2 = Object.keys(mapData)
 .map( key => mapData[key].RegionName  )
 .filter( name => name );
console.dir(regionNames2);
```